# How to switch toggle off/on in Android?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to switch on/off system toggle by pressing Button in my app.

For example, i want to tap my button in app and after that this toggle will switch off
Settings -> Passwords & security -> Privacy -> Use Experinence Programme section -> Send diagnostic data automatically (Off)

Comment: Thanks, @maruf-hassan 
but the question was how to store this path 'Settings -> Passwords & security -> Privacy -> Use Experinence Programme section -> Send diagnostic data automatically' in variable?

It's clear, for example in Windows it's very easy to setup path to any file C:\Program Files\File.txt 
But how to determine a variable with such path Settings -> Passwords & security...?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `Switch()` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isSwitched = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: Text("Switch Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Switch(
          value: isSwitched,
          onChanged: (value){
            setState(() {
              isSwitched=value;
              print(isSwitched);
            });
          },
          activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Change the `setState`, to fit your code.

Comment: Thank you Maruf! 
How to write the path to this toggle Settings -> Passwords & security -> Privacy -> Use Experinence Programme section -> Send diagnostic data automatically (Off)?

Comment: Store the ```Send diagnostic data automatically``` as a boolean variable. Then change it with ```isSwitched``` in the setState.